# Redirecting to multiple page after form submission

Tags: php, html

i have a form. In the action field i have given a page location where the control should redirect after submit. But i want to redirect to multiple page after submit. And the next page should open in new tab. I know about target_blank option. I just want to know how to redirect to multiple pages after submit. Thank you.

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
a simple way to open new tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script in your submit form page

```
 <script>
window.open('link','_blank');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by redirect?
Do you want the submit button to send form data to two pages?

If yes this can be achieved by using session variables and opening a new window on the redirected page.

1) save the form data in session variables.
2) load the 1st page
3) use php script or you can use window.open("url") in the 1st page to redirect to a new page on a new tab.